# Connecting subgraphs programmatically

Tags: c++, python-3.x, igraph, networkx, graph-tool

I am looking for a graph theory package in Python or C++ that enables me to create edges between subgraphs/clusters and their nodes at will, as depicted in the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012036/graphviz-how-to-connect-subgraphs?rq=1), to assign properties to all those objects (the nodes, the clusters, the node-node edges, node-cluster edges, cluster-cluster edges), and perform calculations with those properties.

It appears to be [impossible in NetworkX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51897238/follow-up-add-edge-connecting-nodes-of-two-separate-graphs-in-python-using-netw). Please note I am not referring to merely drawing these images.

**Question**: Does iGraph, graph_tool, or some other package offer this feature?

Comment: Both, networkx and igraph (and I assume graph-tool as well but I have never used it much) model graphs purely as collections of edges. Both have objects corresponding to node clusters or partitions, but there is no notion of node-cluster or cluster-cluster edges. You could implement that pretty easily in a hypergraph / multi-edge graph, for example, but you would have to define the behaviour of such a graph yourself.

Comment: Your comment actually answers all my questions (I was wondering about hypergraphs as well ... learning all of this as I go). If you post it as an answer I'll upvote and accept. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Found this python package for hypergraphs: http://murali-group.github.io/halp/

Their first and last stable release was 2014.